# git rebase branch_name whose changes are on top

Tags: git, rebase

If I run this command:

`git rebase develop` and I'm on the branch `feature/my-awesome-feature`

What happens:

1.) `develop` changes are put on top of `feature/my-awesome-feature` changes

2.) `feature/my-awesome-feature` changes are put on top of `develop` changes

The command would give the impression that the first statement is true seen as I'm on the feature branch and I'm saying rebase develop on it...

But I think it's actually the other way around and the second statement is true... in that while I'm on the feature branch I'm merging in the develop changes and then putting all of the changes of this branch on top of those changes...

Which is the correct statement? And is this the correct way to rebase a branch before opening a PR for a feature branch to the develop branch?

Answer (score 0):

If you rebase, then you are changing the "base" of your branch. You start with the branch on which you want to rebase (`develop`) and then you cherry-pick each commit from the old version of your branch on top of the new base, start with the first divergent commit (the first commit that isn't already in `develop`) up to the last commit.

So, given the following:

```
A -> B -> C -> D (develop)
       \
        > E -> F (feature/my-awesome-feature)
```

If you you currently have `feature/my-awesome-feature` checked out and you run `git rebase develop`, then (assuming there are not conflicts) your `feature/my-awesome-feature` will end up looking like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D (develop) -> E' -> F' (feature/my-awesome-feature)
```

Note that `E'` and `F'` will have different hashes (that is, they are not identical to `E` and `F`) because you've changed the history of those commits.

This is essentially what the [documentation says](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "topic":
>
> ```
>       A---B---C topic
>      /
> D---E---F---G master
> ```
>
> From this point, the result of either of the following commands:
>
> ```
> git rebase master
> git rebase master topic
> ```
>
> would be:
>
> ```
>               A'--B'--C' topic
>              /
> D---E---F---G master
> ```

Comment: So in your opinion we are correct in rebasing the branch we want on to the branch we are on... so `develop` on to our `feature/my-awesome-feature` and not the other way around e.g. `git checkout develop` and `git rebase feature/my-awesome-feature`

Comment: @Cameron Usually you'd want to checkout your feature branch, rebase on your master branch (or merge it in), create your PR, then merge the PR into your master branch.

Comment: @Cameron - If you checkout your master branch and rebase it, you'll be changing it's history, which can cause havoc for anyone else who is working on an issue branch.

Comment: I’m a little confused now... we’re not rebasing master... we’re checking out the feature branch and then rebasing develop on it rather than checking out develop and rebasing the feature on it...

Comment: @Cameron - So you have three branches? `master`, `develop` and `feature`? There's no one right way to use git, but typically you rebase a feature branch only. You would typically avoid rebasing any branch which is shared by multiple developers. This is because a rebase rewrites the history of that branch. If `develop` is shared between multiple developers/branches, then it'll cause major, major headaches if you rewrite its history.

Comment: But that’s my point... we’re not right? As we’re rebasing the latest develop code into our feature so we can get it ready for a merge. Instead of doing it the other way around and then having to branch off again...

Comment: @Cameron - I think I'm having trouble understanding your exact situation and what you're looking to do and why. Could you update your question to explain the 3 branch strategy you are using? Usually `master` is your source of truth, `feature` is where you do your work and an "in-between" branch (`develop`?) is only used if you have some long-running project with multiple PRs that you don't want to introduce into your `master` branch until the end. I'm not sure what you are using your `develop` branch for in this case.